# Print L part of a matrix using single loop

Tags: c++

Let the given matrix is

> {1,2,4}
>
> {3,4,6}
>
> {7,8,9}

It should print 1 3 7 8 9 using single loop.

I have tried like this

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(i!=n-1)
        cout<<a[i][0]<<" ";
    cout<<a[n-1][i]<<" ";
}
```

But it would print 1 7 3 8 9

moreover it would not work when matrix is rectangular

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this but one way would be:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const int width = 3;
    const int height = 4;
    const std::array<std::array<int, width>, height> a = 
    {{
        { 1, 2, 4 },
        { 3, 4, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 },
        { 10, 11, 12 },
    }};

    for(int i=0;i<width + height - 1;i++){
        std::cout<<a[std::min(i, height - 1)][std::max(0, i - height + 1)]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should `#include <algorithm>` to use [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) / [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max).

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < N+M-1; i++)
    {
        if(i < N)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << a[i][0];
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << " " << a[N-1][i-N+1];
        }
    }
```

where N = number of lines and M = number of columns.